# I don't understand this python build synax "python3 setup.py build"

Tags: python, python-3.x, build, installation

Can someone please explain this build syntax here?

```
python3 setup.py build
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/406410/327339

I just used the instructions at the source above to install pygame in python 3.x, and it worked great, but I don't understand the syntax of the commands, and I don't know where to find documentation on it.

`python3 file.py` calls a given module (`file.py` in this case, or `setup.py` above), but what about the word *after* that, ie: "build" in the command above? Is that a built-in Python command, is that a folder where outputs from setup.py are going, or what is it?

Same with the "install" command. Can you please explain that syntax and help me find any relevant documentation? I tried searching around for a while, ex "python3 build", "python 3 module install", "python 3 module build," etc, but can't seem to find anything very informative on the matter.

Also, what exactly are the build and install commands doing?

Note: here is the contents of the "pygame" folder where I am running these commands.

[image]

Comment: It works like any other terminal command: use the `python` executable to run the `setup.py` file with the argument `build`. There is plenty of material out there on `setup.py` installations, this question is very broad as it stands.

Comment: Ah, it's an *argument* to setup.py. I've never written a module requiring an argument like that yet. I'll have to learn about it. Thanks.

Comment: "build" is just a parameter passed into `setup.py`.   Python programs can have their own parameters, and what they are is entirely dependant on the program (setup.py) being run.  Some will take filenames as parameters, some will take user names, many take nothing.  The meaning can only be determined by reading the code or the documentation for the program.

Comment: The arguments are visible in python as a list `sys.argv`.

Comment: Strictly, you're passing two arguments to `python`, which interprets the first argument as a file to execute and pass the arguments along to.

Comment: I just posted an image of the file contents where I am running these commands. I see the `setup.py` file but not any `install` or `build` files. Are these passed as string arguments to setup.py then?

Comment: "The arguments are visible in python as a list sys.argv. – cdarke 9 mins ago"

Comment: Ok, so a list of strings...got it (I think). So now I'm going to go search the `setup.py` module for the words "build" and "install" so I can see where it looks for those arguments to determine what to do.

Answer (score 0):

From my use of Python in the terminal, this command tells Python 'python3', so whatever version of Python 3.x your system is running, 'setup.py' is the Python script you're running and 'build' and 'install' are part of the distutils module to make it easier to install modules.